# How to send http response from setTimeout callback - express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to have custome response time-out, so that I am trying to send the response from `setTimeout` callback if the processing time exceeds certain interval.

In the following example, I set **20ms** as time-out period within which `services.getReport()` has to be processed otherwise the API has to send response as `response_timed_out`.

The following code works fine but it throws exception like

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

```js
router.post("/getReport", (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.send({ status:503, msg: "response_timed_out" });
  }, 20);
  services.getReport(req, res);
});
```

Comment: Is services.getReport calling `res.writeHead(...)` or calling res.send? Check this post for the _Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client_   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client

Comment: you could use `if (res.headersSent) { return; }` or clear the timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback) method on the request object to define timeout time for each route.

```
router.post("/getReport", (req, res) => {
  req.setTimeout(2000);
  services.getReport(req, res);
});
```

You can also define timeout time globally for all routes on the server.

```
const server = app.listen(port, () => {});
server.setTimeout(15000);
```

You can also provide the second argument which is callback that will run when timeout occurs. If you want the callback then you call `setTimeout` on the response.

```
router.post("/getReport", (req, res) => {
  res.setTimeout(2000, () => res.send('timed_out'));
  services.getReport(req, res);
});
```

Comment: This looks good. Is it possible to read the value `req.setTimeout`, which is `2000` in this case, within the `services.getReport` function so that I can check as follows `if (req.timeout >= 2000) res.send('timed_out')`

Comment: The updated one gives error as `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: @Prem It seems that callback is not called if you call it on request but it should work if you call it on response instead.

Comment: The updated one works fine. The only additional thing I have added is `if (!res.headersSent) { res.send(report) }` within `services.getReport` function

Comment: @Prem Shouldn't that throw an error because you can only send headers once?

Comment: Its `!res.headersSent`. I have updated the same in my comment. Thank you